# Package version not in catalog

Tags: meteor

I need to run meteor on a remote server with no internet access. I do development work on a local machine that does have internet access. I copied the entire project directory to the remote machine and ran

```
meteor
```

It returns:

```
While selecting package versions:
error: Package version not in catalog: rzymek:fullcalendar 2.3.1

While refreshing package catalog to resolve previous errors:
error: Network error: wss://packages.meteor.com/websocket: getaddrinfo
ENOTFOUND
```

I thought all necessary files were contained in the project directory? I don't know how to fix this. Running meteor works just fine on my dev machine with the exact same files.

Comment: what does `ls -l packages` give you on your local server (where it is working)?

Comment: `drwxrwxr-x 3 me me 4096 May  5 14:01 npm-container`

Within that are
`-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 273 May  5 13:59 index.js
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 703 May  5 13:59 package.js`

Comment: then you haven't yet installed the dependencies even on the server where this are meant to work, since `rzymek:fullcalendar` is not listed there.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. How does my server run and function correctly if dependencies are not installed? Perhaps they are installed in a different place.

Comment: seems like the behavior has changed. What I was talking about seems no longer true as of the switch from meteorite to proper meteor package management.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that meteor is no longer storing dependencies in the project directory itself, but instead in `~/.meteor/packages`. So bundling up your project directory alone won't be enough. But you can probably write a script that reads from `.meteor/packages` and then grabs the listed packages from `~/.meteor/packages`. You'll still need to think through how to get them in the right place on the remote server, but it should be possible to just place them in the project directory's `packages` directory (though some renaming may be necessary as it seems that meteor replaces the `:` with an `_` in `~/.meteor/packages`).

Comment: Interesting. I decided that was more trouble than it was worth and instead managed to get internet access.